# Abstract model class in django, but with table

Tags: python, django

In Django, if I do an abstract model class, and then have actual derived classes, only these classes will have an associated table, and the abstract class cannot be instantiated by itself. If I remove the abstract=True meta information, then an actual table is created for the base class, but doing so allows client code to create an object of the base class.

Is there a way of forcing client code to always instantiate derived classes, while having a table associated to the base class ?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here, but you could have a "template" class that is abstract, which your derived classes inherit, giving you the shared abstract class to build up your models from to get the tables. Your "base" class need not declare any additional fields.

Comment: @Brandon: if I use an abstract class, then I need to use generic relations. I want my base class to have a table because I want to define foreign keys pointing at its content without having to resort to generic relations, but I also don't want a pure base class to be instantiated by accident.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what the best way to accomplish what you're needing to do.

Comment: What if you attach a custom models.Manager on the base class and "cripple" the `create` method?

Comment: @Brandon: I was just curious. I noted that django does a lot of magic, so maybe there was some magic meta flag to perform what I needed. I don't think it's possible even in pure python, unless you throw an exception in `__init__`...

Comment: Throwing in ``__init__`` wouldn't be too bad of an approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning `None` or raising `NotImplemented` in `__new__` in the class, I don't know if that would affect anything else but its worth a shot.